# What is Intel Speed Step technology?

Tags: netbook, speedstep

My Samsung N145+ Net book specs say that my Intel Atom Processor N455 supports Speed step technology. Is this something that can be activated or is it always working? Is it just a marketing ploy?

Comment: Its not a [marketing ploy](http://www.intel.com/cd/channel/reseller/asmo-na/eng/203838.htm)

Comment: What information have you found as part of your own research? Please include that in your question.

Comment: I think nearly every intel system back to the PIII has had some flavour of speedstep. Its just a way of saying "The processor throttles back to a slower speed to save power"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Intel SpeedStep Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) allows the processor to operate at reduced clock rates in low-load situations to save power

- Every time a transistor switches, it dissipates power. This means that **a processor will consume more power and generate more heat when it runs at faster clock speeds**. In addition, the required CPU core voltage increases as clock rates increase, and power consumption and heat output increase with the *square* of voltage.
- Intel SpeedStep Technology allows the processor to run at a slower clock rate when idle or under a light load. The operating system can set the processor's clock rate to a level appropriate for the load, so that it doesn't waste power running at full speed when it doesn't have much work to do.
- The equivalent AMD technologies are [Cool'n'Quiet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool%27n%27Quiet) and [PowerNow!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerNow!), which are functionally similar to the Intel solution. These solutions are collectively referred to as [dynamic frequency scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).